# What dtrace script output means?

Tags: node.js, restify, dtrace

I am tracing DTrace probes in my restify.js application (restify it is http server in node.js that provides dtrace support). I am using sample dtrace script from restify documentation:

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -s

#pragma D option quiet

restify*:::route-start
{
   track[arg2] = timestamp;
}

restify*:::handler-start
/track[arg3]/
{
   h[arg3, copyinstr(arg2)] = timestamp;
}

restify*:::handler-done
/track[arg3] && h[arg3, copyinstr(arg2)]/
{
   @[copyinstr(arg2)] = quantize((timestamp - h[arg3, copyinstr(arg2)]) / 1000000);
   h[arg3, copyinstr(arg2)] = 0;
}

restify*:::route-done
/track[arg2]/
{
   @[copyinstr(arg1)] = quantize((timestamp - track[arg2]) / 1000000);
   track[arg2] = 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
  use_restifyRequestLogger                          
           value  ------------- Distribution ------------- count    
              -1 |                                         0        
               0 |@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 2        
               1 |                                         0        

  use_validate                                      
           value  ------------- Distribution ------------- count    
              -1 |                                         0        
               0 |@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 2        
               1 |                                         0        

  pre                                               
           value  ------------- Distribution ------------- count    
               0 |                                         0        
               1 |@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                     1        
               2 |@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                     1        
               4 |                                         0        

  handler                                           
           value  ------------- Distribution ------------- count    
             128 |                                         0        
             256 |@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 2        
             512 |                                         0        

  route_user_read                                   
           value  ------------- Distribution ------------- count    
             128 |                                         0        
             256 |@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 2        
             512 |                                         0
```

I was wondering what is `value` value field - what does it mean?
Why there is 124/256/512 for example? I guess it means the time/duration but it is in strange format - is it possible to show `miliseconds` for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram). You are getting a histogram because you are using the `quantize` function in your D script. The [DTrace documentation says the following on quantize](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36846/gkwuk.html#scrolltoc):

> A power-of-two frequency distribution of the values of the specified expressions. Increments the value in the highest power-of-two bucket that is less than the specified expression.

The 'value' columns is the result of `(timestamp - track[arg2]) / 1000000` where timestamp is the current time in nanoseconds. So the value shown is duration in milliseconds.

Putting this all together, the route_user_read result graph is telling you that you had 2 requests that took between 128 and 256 milliseconds.

This output is useful when you have a lot of requests and want to get a general sense of how your server is performing (you can quickly identify a bi-modal distribution for example). If you just want to see how long each request is taking, try using the [printf function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/819-5488/gcfbn.html#gcgfz) instead of quantize.